# Date(dateString) constructor inconsistent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

```
a = new Date('09-01-2013')
//Sun Sep 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)

b = new Date('2013-09-01')
//Sat Aug 31 2013 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)

b < a
//true
```

I did this in the Node.js repl, v0.10.12

Why are the dates different based on the form of the dateString?

I can't see how this is timezone related, since both dates are displayed in local timezone and their values are clearly not equivalent.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: the ctor should be receiving in a [rfc2822 date format](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#page-14) (Any other format should be considered a convenience if it parses correctly or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `new Date('09-01-2013')` and `new Date('2013-09-01')` use different formats/standards and as such are parsed differently.

`new Date('09-01-2013')` is parsed as you would expect and results in a midnight time (in your local time zone). However, `new Date('2013-09-01')` is parsed as an ISO-8601 date at UTC midnight, UTC midnight is then converted to your local timezone when displayed (in this case EDT which is reflected in the `20:00:00`, a 4 hour difference).

**Conclusion**: use `YYYY/MM/DD` to avoid headaches.